# Analytics API .. how do I get list of all reports metadata?

Tags: apex, metadata-api, analytics-api

I am trying to access Reports metadata from Metadata API . Following is the documentation I am using 
[Analytics API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/sforce_analytics_rest_api_get_reportmetadata.htm)

If I have list of report ids , can I extract the metadata of all reports in a single API call ? I am trying to build something dynamic hence I would never know how many reports may get into list and hence sending Id each time with each new call is just not right thing to do...

Is there anyway ?

Comment: Are you using apex or nodejs or any other java code ?

Comment: nodejs - jsforce ( but shudnt matter right?)

Comment: it will matter ..If you are on apex you can use other way apart from API

Comment: Yep , lets say it is Apex. What would be the other way ? I can SOQL Report Ids. But we still cant get Metadata from Apex right?

Comment: got it https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_report_metadata.htm thanks Mohit But still Metadata API doesn't support bulk  is that moral of the story?

Comment: i dont see any harm in running for loops .Also see how to do a batch call in REST .Also note you can run your code asynchronously in node and combine the pipe and use .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using apex to fetch metadata,you can use Report Describe to do run in for loop and should not be doing any harm except if heap size blows off ,so keep variables transient might resuce

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_reports_reportmanager.htm#apex_Reports_ReportManager_describeReport

Use describe report class and pass report Id

```
describeReport(reportId)
```

> Retrieves report, report type, and extended metadata for a tabular, summary, or matrix report.
>
> Report class provides way to run your Report as well

http://peterknolle.com/asynchronous-reports-with-the-analytics-api-in-apex/

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_run_reports.htm?search_text=report

Now lets say you are using in node js ,there are latest features where you can chain the API

http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_api_rest.htm

You can use composite batch resource to trigger independent API

```
{
"batchRequests" : [
{
"method" : "PATCH",
"url" : "v34.0/sobjects/account/001D000000K0fXOIAZ",
"richInput" : {"Name" : "NewName"}
},{
"method" : "GET",
"url" : "v34.0/sobjects/account/001D000000K0fXOIAZ"
  }]
}
```

Comment: @ManjunathNimbal You were my teacher so I owe you lot ..long way to go but thanks for all lessons :)